# Python: associating a description to each combination of itertools.product

Tags: python, python-itertools, cartesian-product

I have a function which runs a numerical simulation. I want to define a number of possible inputs for each parameter, and run the function on all the possible combinations. The way I'm doing it now is with itertools:

```
param1=['London','New York','Paris']
param2=[dataframe1,dataframe2]
param2_description =['optimistic assumptions','conservative assumptions' ]


myprod = itertools.product(param1, param2)
for i in myprod:
    myresult = myfunction(i[0],i[1])
```

My question is: how can I associate a description to each possible value of the parameters, and pass it to the function? In other words, when i[0]=dataframe1, how can I pass 'optimistic assumptions' to my function?

I thought about functions which look for an item in a list, but I'm not sure they would work with all objects, like a pandas dataframe.

Thanks!
PS I don't have to use itertools at all costs, I can consider alternatives based on other approaches.

Comment: Can't you turn `param2_description` into a dictionary `{dataframe1: 'optimistic assumptions', ...}` and then simply pass `param2_description[i[0]]`?

Comment: Doesn't the key of a dictionary need to be a string? Would I be using a dataframe object as the key of a dictionary?

Comment: What do you actually want as output?

Comment: @freakish I can get itertools to iterate over the keys of a dictionary. This will allow me to retrieve both the value and the description. Thanks! I should have thought of that...

Comment: @Pythonistaanonymous Dictionary keys don't have to be strings. They can be any immutable object. But if you found different solution then that's cool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not simply pass the description together with the relevant dataframe as a tuple (or dict or any other datatype that suits your purpose) to `itertools.product`?

Example:

```
In [14]: myprod1 = itertools.product(param1, zip(param2, param2_description)) # remark: replaced the dataframes simply by letters

In [15]: list(myprod1)
Out[15]: 
[('London', ('a', 'optimistic assumptions')),
 ('London', ('b', 'conservative assumptions')),
 ('New York', ('a', 'optimistic assumptions')),
 ('New York', ('b', 'conservative assumptions')),
 ('Paris', ('a', 'optimistic assumptions')),
 ('Paris', ('b', 'conservative assumptions'))]
```

For each item in `myprod1` you can now run the simulation on the dataframe (`item[1][0]`) while you have the description of that dataframe available in `item[1][1]`) and you'll have it for the different cartesian products made by itertools. You could also use a dictionary for this purpose, which is actually a good choice when you have meta-data describing your dataframes.